# Auto-incremented ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-increment primary key in SQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359170/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-tables)

I am working at the moment with SQL Express 2008 and C#. 
In my application, I save some data in the table "buchung" in my database. Well, in this table I need a sequence that starts with 1 and if I save new data, the id should increase.

To my surprise I can´t find anything about this on google.

How can I do this? Can you help me?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359170/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-tables

Comment: plus of course this looks more like a tsql question than a C# one

Comment: I insert into Google "Auto-incremented ID in SQL Server" and gets tons of useful information. How did you search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked into auto-increment with seed as 1 and increment by 1 ...
hope this helps .

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an [IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column on your table.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE buchung
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(20),
    LastName varchar(30)
);
```

The format is `IDENTITY [ (seed , increment ) ]`, where `seed` is the first value, and `increment` is the number that is added for each new row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    myColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting an integer type column to be an "Identity" will do this in SQL Server.

*However* this has a drawback.  If you have a failed transaction then the number that you have created will be lost forever.  If this could cause you problems in integration you need to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a numeric column into your table with identity featured.

[Click for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Alter table dbo.myTable add SeqId int identity(1,1) primary key clustered;

call it ID or SeqId or as you wish. if you alteady have a PK on that table you could make the existing one a unique index and nonclustered. depends on your whole table design.