# How to increase ID in MS SQL database when inserting data via textbox's on ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-increment primary key in SQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359170/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-tables)

i have a question about how i can get auto increase and enter the ID in my MS SQL Database, when i'm inserting data via textbox's on my ASP.NET Website, i will try this guide..

http://mrbool.com/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-csharp-and-asp-net/25091

But as you can see it, the user needs to write an ID, but that's not what i wanted.. Can you help me ? :)

Comment: The ID is assigned by the database; you don't need to write it.

Comment: In SQL Server, define your ID column as an identity and don't give the user any way to edit it. It'll be assigned a number automatically when a record is inserted.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338603.aspx read this it's straight and to the point..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the id column type int and set auto increment property of this field. This is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359170/auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-tables).

Comment: Did you check the article he linked?  It's not coming up for me here, so I can't see it.

Comment: I think you mean "Identity" as this is for SQL Server - AUTO_INCREMENT is for MySql.

Comment: I take it the article writer didn't explain this part.

Comment: Sry that im new on this website... I could just not find it.... But thanks for the help :)